function graph using pstricks & pst-plot
Rephrasing earlier question;
how to express this formula;
f(x) = (2x + 5) / (x^2 + 5x + 4)

for use in pstricks & pst-plot?

Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you specify your question, how far did you get and at which point did you get stuck? Did you read the pst-plot manual on page 7 where plotting mathematical functions is explained? Are you able to plot a different (simpler) function and you are just asking about how exactly this specific function should be written? If you can plot simpler functions, which code (including documentclass and usepackage statements) do you use for this?

@marjin i am able to understand and do simple graphs; however this particular expresssion which creates multiple lines, i was not able to deduce with postscript. now the pst-plot being used is quite old (why thats being used is another story). somehow, the algebraic word is not supported on this pst-plot/pstricks version; i am currently drawing the graphs by supplying the co-ordinates calculated manually, thanks for your help.

run with lualatex
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
    
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-15,-1.5)(5,20)
\psaxes[Dx=2,Dy=2,dx=2,dy=2]{->}(0,0)(-14.5,-0.5)(4.5,19.5)
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,
  plotpoints=2001,yMaxValue=19]{-14.5}{4.5}{(2x+5)/(x^2+5*x+4)}
\psline[linestyle=dashed](-2.5,-1)(-2.5,19)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}


